# Facebook Like Button on Individual Pages

Tags: facebook, social-media, sharing

There have been a few questions like this asked before but not in the same way.  I want to put a Facebook Like or Share or Recommend button on all of my website pages.  The site is somewhat like Yelp but for different topics.

I am wondering which button to put there.  Does it do any good to have individual pages "liked" and does it show anywhere besides on that page?  I basically just want people to be able to click a button and have the page show up on their wall and their friend's feeds and I am not sure what the best plugin for that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend just about anyone to scrap those like/share/recommend or Tweet buttons from their sites. Unless they are essential to your site, they simply add more bloat to your code and slow down the loading time.

That said, the share button would be most useful for you in this situation, since it would create a post that would show up on the user's timeline (not sure it's called a "wall" any longer) and be visible to their friends.

There's a good post with some food for thought on this issue here: http://informationarchitects.net/blog/sweep-the-sleaze/

Answer (score 10):

There are a variety of ways to do this. Basically you need to conform your pages to Facebook's Graph API. Once this is set up correctly, when someone "likes" your page on your site, it's the same as if they liked it on FB. To implement this, you can look at the docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ or if you are using a good cms, there a variety of plugins that make it really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Like button creator on developers.facebook.com 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Enter your website (or individual pages) to generate the code to implement on your site, it's really simple